# Running Linux OS inside Windows with KVM support

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm

I am trying to run a Linux OS inside a Windows machine to develop a Linux application. But the application requires KVM support. However virtual machines such as Virtual Box do not benefit from hardware accelerations and it is required by KVM. How can I create a VM with KVM support?

I searched that docker images can benefit from hardware accelerations but it runs containers in headless mode. It would be really hard to develop, test and debug applications in headless mode. But I am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using WSL on Windows which is natively supported. This is the closest you can get with Windows kvm for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked two VMs running on Windows 7 64-bit under VirtualBox 7.0.6: Ubuntu MATE 23.10 and Linux Mint 21.3. In VirtualBox, I have them both set to Default for System - Acceleration - Paravirtualization Support.

For both,kvm-ok says that KVM is properly configured and ready for use.